# Making sense of legal terms and wording - multiple meanings of "fallo"

Tags: significado, subjuntivo, vocabulario-técnico, género, lenguaje-jurídico

At the conclusion of a (Spanish) transcription of legal proceedings, the following text appears:

> Ejecutoriado que sea fallo, confiérase copia certificada para que sea subinscrito en el Registro Civil.

I can't quite make sense of the English:

> Executed that it be judgment [failure?], confer it certified copy so that it be recorded in the Civil Register.

Note the pervasive use of the subjunctive mood, plus the impersonal (formal) imperative.

I get the basic meaning, but I seem to be tripping on the mechanics of the formal court Spanish in the original.  How might this be better translated for "layperson speak"?

Side question:  Should I assume the masculine [past-participle-as-noun](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/77587) "subinscrito" has *fallo* as its agent? (My first thought was that this was mismatched gender for *copia*.)

Second side question:  Is there any historical etymology behind [*fallo*](https://translate.google.com/#es/en/fallo) meaning both "judgment" and "failure"? (I suppose the two English terms could be related, but then that's more of a philosophical and semantics debate.)

Comment: P.S. Translating a legal proceeding or summary from one language to another is a great way to learn the foreign language. :)

Comment: **[Ejecutoriar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ES7yhF0)**: _Der._ Dar firmeza de cosa juzgada a un fallo o pronunciamiento judicial. [I have learnt something new today.]

Comment: @pr1268 Provided you are equally exposed to Spanish in daily use. Otherwise people will look at you like Don Quixote when you try using things like the future subjunctive: "El que recibiere la mayoría de los votos será presidente". I've been learning from reading, and it's like a different language from what people are using.

Comment: I posted an answer to **one** of your side questions. Please, realize that it is against the philosophy of this site to have multiple questions in one post, since then it is difficult to search for this content later. If someone was to look for the etymology of "fallar" probably would not click on a question titled "Making sense of legal terms and wording - help translating document". Also, it is more difficult to upvote content and make best answers "float" to the top. Since there's 3 questions in 1, answers will be less targeted, content will be all over the place... Avoid this in the future

Comment: About your P.S. For an ordinary Spanish speaker, understanding judicial language is very difficult. It is archaic, and I suspect it is intentionally obscure and overly cultured. It use constructions and words that serve no one in any other context. So I do not agree that it's a good way to learn Spanish.

Comment: There are instructions to make the judicial language less archaic and more "affordable" to the common citizen. [Informe de la Comisión para la Modernización del lenguaje jurídico (2011)](http://lenguajeadministrativo.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/cmlj-recomendaciones.pdf)

Comment: Following @Diego 's suggestion, you can still [edit] the side questions out and generate good and interesting questions from them. It is not even suggested, but recommended. This way, every question will have its own space in the form of title, body and answers, and will be more easily reachable by future users. All in all, we want to create a good source of resources for the people.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm afraid the phrase in question lacks the article. The correct phrase is: *Ejecutoriado que sea **el** fallo, ...*

Notice that google searches ([Searches](https://www.google.com.ar/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22ejecutoriado%20que%20sea%20el%20fallo%22)) show more than 2,600 results for the phrase with "el", and only one without it: your question at this site.

Judgments (or decrees) are of course executed (signed) by the judge and, as a result, **enforced**, that is, put into practice. "ejecutoriado" is closer to this idea of "enforcement". ([Supporting source](http://www.proz.com/kudoz/spanish_to_english/law_general/1221401-ejecutoriado.html))

To translate something legal in the subjunctive passive form (it can be regarded as imperative, or as the subordinate clause of "Ordeno que se confiera"), two formulas can be used:

- May X be + past participle ...

OR

- Be X + past participle ...

A good translation is not one that makes the text understandable for the layperson. A good translation is one that imitates the original to the extent that nothing is lost -- not only the content of the original, but also its style. A good literary translation needs to sound literary, a good technical translation needs to sound technical, and a good legal translation needs to sound legal, not like everyday speech.

"subinscripto" does refer to "fallo" (masculine). The point is that the **primary** record of the judgment will remain in court, while a copy is being requested for the judgment to be **also** entered in the Civil Register (the book) or filed with the Civil Registry (the office). What I mean to make clear at this point is that "registro" is ambiguous in Spanish. This **second** entry or recording counts as a secondary filing (*subinscripción*).

A possible translation could be:

- **Once the judgment has been enforced, may a certified copy thereof (be made to) be filed with the Civil Registry / recorded/entered in the Civil Register.** (I think "be made of" can be omitted, as it is implicit that a copy will need to be made to be able to proceed with its filing.)

Sorry I can't help with the etymology of "fallar" and "fallo". In English, we can say that a judge or court pronounces/renders/passes/issues a judgment (*emite/pronuncia/dicta una sentencia/un fallo* or just *falla*).

Comment: The etymology of _fallo_ could be a good question if you want to ask it in a new post. I thought it had the same origin as _hallar_ (rendering _fallo_ into a synonym of _hallado_), but it is not so.

Answer (score 3):

Most importantly in this sentences, besides the baroque subjunctive gymnastics, is the meaning of **Fallo**. It's easy to mistake the word and translate it as *Failure,* since there is a homonym in Spanish with that very meaning and is used more frequently that the legalese. (I believe the term in translation lore  is that Failure is a *false friend* to Fallo)

However, as Failing is a verb, it must be noted that in the word used in legalese is actually a **substantive**. Even though you may hear that a judge or tribunal "falla" (as a verb) the correct wording is they **Emitir un fallo** equivalent in English to *pass judgement*

**Fallo** Is then not a word but an actual product of the judge's or authorities action by **emiting** it.

So **Un fallo** can be an order of redress in favor of one of the parties, it can also come in the form of a punishment for a guilty party or it can be a settlement to reach peace. In every case, **Fallo** comes down to be a **decision** by someone with authority on a discussed matter, in order to end it.

The common idiom: ***"El Fallo del respetable siempre es inapelable"*** (used in show business mainly) means that there is no appeal possible once the audience has passed judgement on your performance (*El respetable* Is short for *El respetable público* but in an idiomatic way. So literally, *the honorable audience passed judgement, and no appeal is possible.*

Comment: Regarding the use of _fallo_, in Argentina it remains more usual (to my knowledge) to say _fallo_ only when referring to a court judgment, as in _el fallo del juez X_ and _falla_ for "failure", as in _una falla del sistema_.

Comment: Agreed. Also, term does lend itself to ironic humor, especially when the judgement is against ones interest, it's too tempting to deem the "Fallo" as a "Failure" in the part of the judge

Answer (score 3):

De acuerdo a [Etimologias de Chile](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?fallar):

- Fallar (de decidir) viene del latí *afflare* (soplar hacia algo, olfatear). De ese verbo también procede *hallar*.
- Fallar (de fracasar o no conseguir) viene de *falla* (falta, defecto), relacionada con *fallax* (mentiroso) y el verbo *fallere* (engañar). De esta raíz tenemso también `falacia`, `falencia` y `falaz` (y por supuesto `fallo`).